# SQL - Join on contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, contains

I have two tables like so

```
Table A
server_name
start_time
end_time

Table B
id
description
```

What I want to do is join the two tables together so it looks like this

```
Table C
server_name
start_time
end_time
id
description
```

The only way I can make the join is if I search for the server_name in the description.

I have tried using the like function but this doesn't work. It needs to be exactly what is in server_name column in the description

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```
select *
from tableA ta
join tableB tb on tb.description like '%' + ta.server_name + '%'
```

The `+` is SQL Server concatenation. ANSI SQL has `||`, and others have `concat` instead.

Extended version, add space before/after:

```
select *
from tableA ta
join tableB tb on ' ' + tb.description + ' ' like '% ' + ta.server_name + ' %'
```

Takes care of Matt Gibson's test/greatest example too.

Comment: Although, of course, if `ta.server_name` is "test" and the `tb.description` is "The greatest server in the world!" this will match, so whether this will work perfectly depends on what kind of stuff is actually in `description`.

Comment: I am using SQL server so I have tried + instead of ||

Comment: Matt - I know that will match, I'm just trying to get some matches in first. After running the query above it is 10 minutes and counting and there is on a few 100 rows of data.

Comment: @DeanFlaherty Searching with `LIKE` with a wildcard at the *beginning* of the string is never going to be that fast if you have lots of data. It can't use an index even if you've got one, because indexes work by sorting things into order, and a match on '%whatever%' could obviously be at any position in the index. (It's not a ["search argument", or a SARGable query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), in SQL Server terms.)